# Javascript stop Loading scripts and may load scripts again if user consents

Tags: javascript, execution

I am trying to implement GDPR solution. Need to stop the certain scripts either functions or src scripts.
I am able to identify the scripts using "var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");" and iterate thru them after page is loaded.
How do i stop them from being executed. Need eventlistener etc..

If you have any working code it would be helpful. I found somethere that the script type is changed to text/plain etc.. so the script will not be executed and after getting consent, the type is changed back to script/javascript and loaded onto the page dynamically.

How do I do this?
Your help is appreciated.
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

hey i don't understand what you trying to achieve but i have an idea 
if you wanna fire a certain script after doing for example `action A`

have empty `<script></script>`

```
const script = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

if (action A == true){
// the path to the script file
script.src ='js/script.js'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to stop the scripts from loading. I wanted to load them again after the user gives GDPR consent. your script helps after the user gives the consent. I am looking for a way to stop the script execution declared on the page.